# Enbedded Tomcat configuration in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat

I was going through the tomcat configuration for embedded tomcat in spring boot [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties), I was not able to get **prestartminSpareThreads** property for embedded tomcat. However this **prestartminSpareThreads** is available in tomcat [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html). Could you please help me with setting up this property in embedded tomcat?